# Conditional Response Assertion in JMeter

Tags: http, jmeter

I have a requirement wherein a server can send 200 OK or 409 conflict for a given GET/PUT/DELETE request to a resource. Based on the situation and context at that point of time, server can either send 200 OK or 409 and for me both are valid. How can I define Response assertion for this case. Also, if 200 OK is sent with content (for GET), how do I add in response assertion to validate the md5sum of the received content and compare it against the expected one?

Can all these requirements can be put in single assertion?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to get response code as follows:

- Add a Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the request you need to check
- Populate it as follows:

  - Reference name: anything meaningful, i.e. `code`
  - Regular expression: `(\d+)`
  - Template: `$1$`

Other fields can be left blank.

Then add 2 [If Controllers](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) with the following conditions at the same level as your request:

- `${code}==200` - for response code 200
- `${code}==409` - for response code 409

Put all relevant logic under If Controllers (as children).

In order to perform MD5 hash assertion you can use [MD5Hex Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion) provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either **'Response Asstertion'** or  **Beanshell Assertion**

**Response Assertion:**

[image]

**Beanshell Assertion:**

```
if(prev.getResponseCode().equals("403") && prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains("EXPECTED CONTENT"))
{
    prev.setResponseOK();
}
```

To do conditional validation, use Beanshell Assertion, it is very easy and flexible.